# Makes two JPanels when I only need one

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
package Rectangle;
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rectangle extends JFrame { 


  public Rectangle(String arg) { 

      JPanel panel = new JPanel(); enter code here
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("1676858-livingforest2011.jpg")); 
        JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        panel.add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel); 

      }
          public static void main(String[] args) {
          Rectangle forestFrame = new Rectangle(args.length == 0 ? null : args[0]);
          forestFrame.setSize(1698,770);
          forestFrame.setVisible(true); 
          new Rectangle("/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/2njk8eq.png").setVisible(true);



      }
    }
```

It prints out two Jpanels, one that I want and one that I don't. It also prints out the one that I want the size that I want and the second one is the smallest it can be. How do I get rid of the second Jpanel?

Comment: Replace `new Rectangle("/Users.../")` with `forestFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

You create 2 `Rectangle` objects via `new` operator, which creates 2 `JPanel` instances.
Abandon creating one of them.